# Firebase rewrite path to function not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I want to add dynamic meta tags to index.html, the app is created with create-react-app and hosted on firebase hosting. I referred to the post here: https://medium.com/@jalalio/dynamic-og-tags-in-your-statically-firebase-hosted-polymer-app-476f18428b8b

I have created a new cloud function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.host = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'].toLowerCase();
 let indexHTML = fs.readFileSync('./hosting/index.html').toString();
 const path = req.path ? req.path.split('/') : req.path;
 const ogPlaceholder = '<meta name="functions-insert-dynamic-meta">';
 indexHTML = indexHTML.replace(ogPlaceholder, getOpenGraph());
 console.log(indexHTML);
 res.status(200).send(indexHTML);
});

const defaultDesc = 'Test Desc';
const defaultTitle = 'Test Title';
const defaultLogo = 'http://test-domain.com/logo.png';

const getOpenGraph = () => {
 let og = `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123123123" />`;
 og += `<meta property="og:type" content="website" />`;
 og += `<meta property="og:title" content="${defaultTitle}" />`;
 og += `<meta property="og:description" content="${defaultDesc}" />`;
 og += `<meta property="og:image" content="${defaultLogo}" />`;
 og += `<meta property="og:url" content="https://gifmos-frontend-beta.firebaseapp.com/" />`;
 return og;
};
```

and changed rewrite rules as:

```
{
 "hosting": {
 "public": "build",
 "ignore": [
 "firebase.json",
 "**/.*",
 "**/node_modules/**"
 ],
 "rewrites": [
 {
 "source": "**",
 "function": "host"
 }
 ]
 }
}
```

Now the expected result is when we hit: https://my-app-4b3d0.firebaseapp.com/ the HTML should have  replaced with dynamic meta tags from the function written above. But it does not seem to be working. Calling a cloud function returns value as expected: https://us-central1-my-app-4b3d0.cloudfunctions.net/host but we need this to work for "index.html" file call, so we can add dynamic OG tags based on page asked.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a static `index.html` in your public directory, just delete it.

Still if you don't see your custom page, try to `hard reload and empty cache` in the browser(in chrome).

Firebase uses `index.html` if there is any in your public directory and ignores your function in the respective path/url.

Comment: Hey accept it as an answer. I guess you (@Vipul Limbachiya) were facing the same issue